# Deleting key/value pairs from perl result in Global symbol requires explicit package name error

Tags: perl, variables, hash, cgi

I am trying to delete certain key/value pairs from a hash, but I get the Global symbol requires explicit package name exception and I don't know how to debug this. I read up on some solutions, but none of them seem to work. So the hash is declared in this fashion:

```
my $hash = foo();
```

then I go through the hash using this line of code:

```
while (my ($key, $value) = each %$hash)
```

and in the block I select values I don't want and store the keys for these values in an array that was declared like this (before the loop of course):

```
my @keysArray = ();
```

I then access the array to retrieve the keys using this code so I can delete them from the hash:

```
for my $key (@keysArray){
    delete $hash{$key};# this line of code is causing the problem
}
```

The last line that I wrote is the one causing the Global symbol "%hash" requires explicit package name exception.

Any fixes or am I doing something wrong here.

P.S. I changed the variable names and removed other internal code, but the format is the same.

Help please!
Thanks.

Comment: From the error message it seems you are doing "use strict;", which is a good thing. I assume you're doing "use warnings;" as well.

Comment: No warnings, but I got the answer I was looking for (it's below).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`delete $hash{$key}` deletes an entry from `%hash`. There is no `%hash`. Instead you want to write `delete $hash->{$key}`, which deletes an entry from `%$hash`.

I suggest [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for answering all of your questions about references and how to use them.

Answer (score 3):

You've declared `$hash` (a scalar reference to a hash) but not `%hash` (a hash). Try doing `delete $hash->{$key}` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your (repaired) code:

```
for my $key (@keysArray) {
    delete $hash->{$key};
}
```

can be shortened to

```
for my $key (@keysArray) {
    delete $$hash{$key};
}
```

or simply

```
delete @$hash{@keysArray};
```